# Adding points along line by clicking on it using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, snapping, digitizing

ArcGIS for Desktop 10.6.1.

I have a polyline (old railroad track). I'd like to add the train stops as points along it by clicking on the places. I have georeferenced historical maps as the background and can see the train stops on it.

The help files all point to the Construct Points tool, but with that tool, I have to select distances or equal distance, or number of points. I don't see an option for clicking on the line.

If I just generate points (create a new point file and just click), then then points may not be on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up Snapping so that Edge Snapping is on then you should see a SnapTip to tell you that the points you are digitizing are all on that line.

From [About snapping](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-snapping.htm) (with my bolding):

> Snapping allows you to create features that connect to each other so
>   your edits are more accurate, with fewer errors. When snapping is
>   turned on, your pointer will jump, or snap to, **edges**, vertices, and
>   other geometric elements when your pointer is near them and within a
>   certain tolerance. This enables you to position a feature easily in
>   relation to the locations of other features.